# Is there a simple way to navigate between tabs of tabview with primefaces without using wizard?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I am trying to do a page with 3 tabs and I want user to navigate between tabs by "next" and "back" buttons without using wizard. But user cannot navigate after second tab. Where is the mistake I could not find?
Here is my html code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        template="template/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="body">

        <h:form  prependId="false" id="form">
        <p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanel" binding="#{myBean.tabView}" dynamic="true">

        <!-- FIRST TAB -->
                <p:tab id="person" title="Person">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">              
                     <h:outputText value="name" />
                     <p:inputText value="#{myBean.user.firstname}" label="Name" </p:inputText> 
    <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextButton}" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true"/>
               </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>                     

 <!-- SECOND TAB -->
                <p:tab id="adres" title="Address">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                      <h:outputText value="Phone" />
                      <p:inputMask id="phone" value="#{myBean.user.phone}" mask="1999999999" required="true" requiredMessage="ERROR AT PHONE NUMBER"/>
    <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextButton2}" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>

                <!-- THIRD TAB -->
                <p:tab title="Contact">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>             

            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>      
        </ui:define>    
        </ui:composition>
```

And Here is my myBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean") 
@ViewScoped 
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

private User user = new User(); 

 private TabView tabView;

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
      this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    public void nextButton()
    {
        tabView.setActiveIndex(1);
    }

    public void nextButton2()
    {
        tabView.setActiveIndex(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it just an error in the question, your tags for `tab` and `panelGrid` are not closed for your first 2 tabs.

Comment: But I did not get any error. Did you try and get error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Approach 1

You have some unclosed Tags. After i changed the code as follows and it worked for me.

***tabs.xhtml***

```
<h:form  prependId="false" id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanel" binding="#{myBean.tabView}" dynamic="true" activeIndex="0">

        <!-- FIRST TAB -->
        <p:tab id="person" title="Person">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">              
                <h:outputText value="name" />
                <p:inputText value="???USERINFO???" label="Name" />
                <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextButton}" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true"/>
           </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>


        <!-- SECOND TAB -->
        <p:tab id="adres" title="Address">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:outputText value="Phone" />
                <p:inputMask id="phone" value="???USERINFO???" mask="1999999999" required="true" requiredMessage="ERROR AT PHONE NUMBER"/>
                <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextButton2}" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>

        <!-- THIRD TAB -->
        <p:tab title="Contact">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:outputText value="CONTACT" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>    
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

***MyBean.java***

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean") 
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2431097566797234783L;

    private TabView tabView;

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }

    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
      this.tabView = tabView;
    }

    public void nextButton()
    {
        tabView.setActiveIndex(1);
    }

    public void nextButton2()
    {
        tabView.setActiveIndex(2);
    }
}
```

## Approach 2

For me switching from `ViewScoped`to `RequestScoped`did the trick.
If i were you, i would do the following:

Remove the binding from the `tabView`.

```
<p:tabView id="tabPanel" widgetVar="tabPanel" dynamic="true">
```

Switch tabs with `JavaScript`.

```
<p:button onclick="PF('tabPanel').select(1);return false;" value="NEXT" />
```

...instead of...

```
<p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextButton}" update=":form:tabPanel" immediate="true"/>
```

## Approach 3

This third approach works with `ViewScoped` bean and without binding.

Remove the binding and map the `activeIndex` of the `TabView` to a property.

```
<p:tabView id="tabPanel" dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{myBean.activeIndex}">
```

On the next button, call an action which increments the `activeIndex` property.

```
<p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextTab}" update=":form:tabPanel" />
```

***tabs.xhtml***

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabPanel" dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{myBean.activeIndex}">

        <!-- FIRST TAB -->
        <p:tab id="person" title="Person">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">              
                <h:outputText value="name" />
                <p:inputText value="???USERINFO???" label="Name" />
                <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextTab}" update=":form:tabPanel" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>                     

        <!-- SECOND TAB -->
        <p:tab id="adres" title="Address">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:outputText value="Phone" />
                <p:inputMask id="phone" value="???USERINFO???" mask="1999999999" required="true" requiredMessage="ERROR AT PHONE NUMBER"/>
                <p:commandButton  value="NEXT" action="#{myBean.nextTab}" update=":form:tabPanel" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>

        <!-- THIRD TAB -->
        <p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>             

    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

***MyBean.java***

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean") 
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private int activeIndex = 0;

    public int getActiveIndex() {
        return activeIndex;
    }

    public void setActiveIndex(int activeIndex) {
        this.activeIndex = activeIndex;
    }

    public void nextTab() {
        activeIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed as RequestScoped and tried again bu again made no difference. I still cannot pass to the third tab from second tab.

Comment: I tried again. I copied your suggestion but I still cannot reach the third tab. I am opening this tabbed page from a mainpage and this main page is with @ViewScoped. Can this effect?

Comment: Please check your browser for JavaScript errors.
I added a second approach to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried again. At console gives error: primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:1 Uncaught TypeError: a[h].refresh is not a function  and also this error: index.jsf:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: PF is not defined

Comment: Do you added all Primefaces/PrimeUI dependencies correctly?

Comment: Yes I think.Did you add a new dependency while trying this problem?

Comment: What version of Primefaces do you use?
If you use an older version than PrimeFaces 3, you can try to use "PrimeFaces.widgets.yourWidgetVar" instead of "PF('yourWidgetVar')".

Comment: my version is 3.5 but I dont know why it does not work.

Comment: Yes I tried it too. But it did not work for me. In the debug mode I saw that nextTab() method is used only once. When user clicks on Next button from second tab it does not increment and debugger also does not go nextTab() button it only uses this method once. Why this happens I dont know.

Comment: It passed to the third tab after adding this to the button ajax="false"

Comment: Nice, but i think you still have some Javascript problems because it should also work with ajax...

Comment: JavaScript problem? where is my mistake I could not find it.